# Inheriting properties from a parent object

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

All,

If I have a class like so:

```
class MyClass {
     var $height;
     var $width;

     function setDimensions($height,$width) {
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width  = $width;
     }
}
```

And another class like so...

```
class AnotherClass extends MyClass {
     var $color;
     var $speed;

     function setFeatures($color,$speed) {
        $this->color  = $color;
        $this->speed  = $speed;
     }

     function showAll() {
        echo "Color: ".$this->color."<br />";
        echo "Speed: ".$this->speed."<br />";
        echo "Height: ".$this->height."<br />";
        echo "Width: ".$this->width."<br />";
     // echo "Height: ".parent::height."<br />";
     }
}
```

Then I do this:

```
$firstClass = new MyClass();
$firstClass->setDimensions('200cm', '120cm');

$secondClass = new AnotherClass();
$secondClass->setFeatures('red','100mph');

$secondClass->showAll();
```

It does not print the properties defines in the $firstClass. This is understandable as they are two separate instances/objects. How can I pass the properties from one object to another? Would I need to do something like `$secondClass = new AnotherClass($firstClass)`  and pass it that way?

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are different instances.

In this example there is one instance which is being both AnotherClass and  MyClass at the same time

```
$firstClass = new AnotherClass();
$firstClass->setDimensions('200cm', '120cm');
$firstClass->setFeatures('red','100mph');

$firstClass->showAll();
```

None of this classes is abstract.

In your example, the following statements are true:

- $secondClass is a AnotherClass
- $secondClass is a MyClass
- $firstClass  is a MyClass
- $firstClass  is not a AnotherClass

Also, please do not use `var` to define classes properties.

Use either `private`, `public` or `protected`:

```
class MyClass {
     public $height;
     public $width;
```

Comment: That does the trick. Would this be an example of an abstract class?

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning what `private` `protected` and `public` is. You'll get my upvote. @Darius No this is not an example of an abstract class, this is just inheritence.